# subdomain gives access to folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have created one sub-domain. It is also accessed via folder.
For example,

```
subdomain.website.com
```

which is also accessed in the following url

```
website.com/subdomain
```

How do i stop this? I think it can be done with htaccess. I am not sure.

Comment: Have you tried ask provider for advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the htaccess file in `website.com`'s document root, add these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain.website.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^subdomain/?(.*)$ http://subdomain.website.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

add following line in the `.htaccess` in your root directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://subdomain.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```